Bootstrap 5 "row" turn into "flex-row" with horizontal scroll bar in Mobile devices only
I have some images in bootstrap "row" & "col" div. For Mobile devices I want to turn this into flex-row with horizontal scroll bar.
The caveat is it need to preserve "col" & "row" for desktop devices
Here is sample code for desktop devices
Desktop cols
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-success">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-danger">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-info">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-warning">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth ">Card</div>
    </div>

For mobile devices (with horizontal scrollbar)
Mobile cols with horizontal scrollbar
    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap">
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-success">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-danger">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-info">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-warning">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth ">Card</div>
    </div>


Is there any css solution available.

First option is two separate "div" for mobile & desktop, It contains images and I don't know if both the "div" download images twice ?
Second option is to use javascript to detect device type and swap "row" class to "d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap" on load, if there is no css solution.
Here is snippet


.setwidth {
      min-height: 100px;
      min-width: 100px;
      margin : 15px;    
    }
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container pb-5">
        <h2 class="font-weight-light">For PC/wider screen</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-success">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-danger">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-info">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-warning">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth ">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-success">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-danger">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-info">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-warning">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth ">Card</div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="container pb-5">
    <div class="position-relative overflow-auto py-2">
        <h2 class="font-weight-light">Turn above code for Mobile/small devices</h2>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap">
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-success">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-danger">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-info">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-warning">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth ">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-success">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-danger">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-info">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-warning">Card</div>
            <div class="col-2 setwidth ">Card</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>




Should probably be enough, if you overwrite the display property for the larger displays, to set it to block again - by adding d-md-block (or from whatever breakpoint upwards you actually want the block behavior.) flex-row and flex-nowrap do not have any effect to begin with, when display: block applies.

Adding d-md-block turns col-2 aligned in rows and not preserve col

Can you please provide a proper [mre] of the issue then? The snippets shown above so far don't actually render like your screenshots show.

Uploaded snippet, that I expected for mobile devices

I got "css only" solution after some findings. Adding media query for small device solved my problem.
Here is the snippet


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .set_if_mobile {
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
    flex-direction: row !important;
    position: relative !important;
    display: flex !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
    --bs-gutter-x: 0;
    --bs-gutter-y: 0;
  }
}

.setwidth {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin : 15px;    
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container pt-5 pb-5">
    <h2 class="font-weight-light">Only css solution</h2>
    <h4> Just set @media query for small devices </h4>
    <div class="row set_if_mobile">
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-success">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-danger">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-info">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-warning">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth ">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-success">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-danger">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-info">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-warning">Card</div>
        <div class="col-2 setwidth ">Card</div>
    </div>
</div>



Thanks all

.horizontal-scroll {
    display: flex !important;
    overflow-x: auto !important;
}

The above one is css and the bottom is html in small screen
<div class="d-flex d-lg-none d-xl-none d-xxl-none horizontal-scroll">
    <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-success">Card</div>
    <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-danger">Card</div>
    <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-info">Card</div>
    <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-warning">Card</div>
    <div class="col-2 setwidth ">Card</div>
</div>

The bottom is in large screen
<div class="d-none d-lg-flex row">
    <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-success">Card</div>
    <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-danger">Card</div>
    <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-info">Card</div>
    <div class="col-2 setwidth bg-warning">Card</div>
    <div class="col-2 setwidth ">Card</div>
</div>


You can use the above Code!!

This is as bad as an answer can be. Try this code is not the way to answer a question. Please read the help section.

No working, My point is to not write HTML code for diff. devices. To be precise I want the same "col" blocks (PC screen) display in "row" (Mobile screen) with horizontal scrollbar.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
